# NFC Host Emulation not supported with NCI adapters

Tags: android, nfc, hce

**Device Info:**

- CyanogenMod 10.1 rom on 4.2.2 on rooted Nexus 4
- Setup `nfcee_access.xml` file with my certificate.

**Background:**

I'm trying to test an app with Card Emulation on an NFC reader, however my activity's `onNewIntent()` method is not getting triggered. I've tried setting the `launchMode` to be `singleTop`, but no luck either.

Upon further investigation I noticed the following error on logcat some time after I tap on the NFC reader, which I suspect may be the issue:

```
E/NativeNfcManager(824): NFC Host Emulation not supported with NCI adapters
```

**Does anyone know what this error means?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NCI is the [NFC Controller Interface specification](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/). This is the new API that Android uses for NFC devices, since 4.2. Host emulation (i.e. card emulation by an app) has never been an official feature of Android. Apparently, Cyanogenmod also does not support it on NCI-based devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take a look if there's an updated rom that supports it